# How to encapsulate event type member in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I can create getter and setter for an int member. How to do this if this member is an event type ?

Update: I want to call another method each time this member is set.

Comment: yes but that is an event

Comment: Please read what Jon Skeet has to say on this: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx .  Pay particular attention to the thread safety section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Events are in fact ready for consumption, put very simply, declaring an event is actually defining a getter/setter for the underlying delegate and it is therefore not necessary to define explicit getter/setter.

If you want to do some kind of custom handling for the attach/detach of handlers to the event then you can take a look at the following MSDN documentation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ka55h8.aspx

Comment: Thanks will look at them: maybe that's what I need. I want to call another method each time this member is set.

Comment: Can't see how though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765515/how-to-call-a-method-when-adding-an-event-in-c-using-custom-event-accessors

Comment: @user310291, I added an answer to your new question that you referenced.

Answer (score 8):

You can implement [custom event accessors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx).

Example:

```
public delegate int DoSomething();
private event DoSomething _somethingHappened;
public event DoSomething SomethingHappened
{
  add { _somethingHappened += value; }
  remove { _somethingHappened -= value; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Events are declared using a delegate type - simply make your property the delegate type.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx):

> In the .NET Framework class library, events are based on the EventHandler delegate and the EventArgs base class.

```
public EventHandler MyEvent {get; set;}
```

Comment: I want to call another method each time this member is set. If I use this syntax I can't.