# How to call a method when adding an event in c# using custom event accessors?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx

It's not clear for me how I would do this.

Update: Since some people have answered how these moderators pretend that the question is vague ?!!!

Comment: Not clear on how you would do what exactly?  The article explains it pretty clearly, it's just wrapping the subscription in an accessor.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is not clear to you.  You didn't explain it.

Comment: Since some people have answered how these moderators pretend that the question is vague ?!!!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple example of how you can handle a custom event accessor, I understand that you want to call a function each time an event handler is attached/detached from the event. In this case you would need to create a private backing delegate `myCustomEventDelegate` in the code below, and have your custom event accessor `add/remove` blocks add/remove the handler to the delegate and of course invoke your additional functionality.

In this example I just write to the console, of course that is not a great idea if your code is part of a library that could be used in different type of applications that might not have access to the console, but it is just an example after all.

```
using System;

namespace CustomEventDemo
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      TheClassExposingYourEvent instance = new TheClassExposingYourEvent();

      instance.MyCustomEvent += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Program_MyCustomEvent);
      instance.DoSomething();
      instance.MyCustomEvent -= new EventHandler<EventArgs>(Program_MyCustomEvent);

      Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Program_MyCustomEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("The event was fired");
    }
  }

  class TheClassExposingYourEvent
  {
    private EventHandler<EventArgs> _myCustomEventDelegate;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyCustomEvent
    {
      add
      {
        _myCustomEventDelegate += value;
        // Do something extra here.
        // Writing to the console is a bad example!!!
        Console.WriteLine("Event handler attached");
      }
      remove
      {
        _myCustomEventDelegate -= value;
        // Do something extra here.
        // Writing to the console is a bad example!!!
        Console.WriteLine("Event handler detached");
      }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
      if (_myCustomEventDelegate != null)
      {
        _myCustomEventDelegate(this, EventArgs.Empty);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much will read other answers to see which one is best suited for me.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be like this?

```
    event EventHandler IDrawingObject.OnDraw
    {
        add
        {
            lock (PreDrawEvent)
            {
                PreDrawEvent += value;
            }
            YourFunction();  // HERE
        }
```

Comment: that's the idea I think.

Answer (score 1):

Events are actually non-public delegates that are wrapper by add/remove accessors to limit how an external class can modify the delegate.  The below code, while lengthy gives a detailed explanation of delegates and events.  It comes from an example project I put together for coworkers trying to learn .Net. Read it from top to bottom like a book (comments are added for explanation, but the code compiles):

```
// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288459(VS.71).aspx

// delegates are a lot like function pointers and events "appear" to be a lot like delegates.
// in a sense, a delegate is a function pointer class.  below is an example declaration
// of a delegate with an int return value, and two parameters (bool, string)
public delegate int MyDelegate(bool abool, string astring);

// delegates behind the scenes are actually of the System.MulticastDelegate type, and therefore
// can have multiple invocations.
// see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx

class DelegatesAndEvents
{

    // delegates can also be defined inside classes
    public delegate void AnotherDelegate();

    // Delegates can be instantiated just like any variable or field
    public AnotherDelegate DelegateInstance;

    public DelegatesAndEvents()
    {
        // add method/delegate to the invocation list
        DelegateInstance += Method;
        // or another syntax
        DelegateInstance += new AnotherDelegate(Method);

        // remove a method/delegate to the invocation list
        DelegateInstance -= Method;
        // or the more formal syntax
        DelegateInstance -= new AnotherDelegate(Method);

        // set the invocation list to a single method/delegate
        DelegateInstance = Method;
        // or the more formal syntax
        DelegateInstance = new AnotherDelegate(Method);

        // to clear a delegate, assign it to null:
        DelegateInstance = null;

        // for all the previous operators, its very important to note
        // that they instantiate a new MulticastDelegate in the process.
        // this means that every add (+=) or remove(-=) generates a new
        // MulticastDelegate.  Look at the following scenario:
        DelegateInstance = Method;

        // invoking a will call Method
        AnotherDelegate a = DelegateInstance;

        DelegateInstance += AnotherMethod;
        // now, invoking a will still only invoke Method, while
        // invoking DelegateInstance will invoke both Method
        // and AnotherMethod.

        // NOTE NOT BEST PRACTICE SEE BELOW
        a(); // invokes Method
        DelegateInstance(); // invokes Method and AnotherMethod

        // The main importance of this fact deals with thread safety
        // when invoking delegates.  When invoking a delegate, you
        // should always do a null-check before invocation to avoid
        // an exception:

        // NOTE NOT BEST PRACTICE SEE BELOW
        if (a != null)
        {
            a();
        }

        // the problem with the above code is that if another thread removes
        // Method from a, after the null check, trying to invoke a will throw
        // an exception.  To get around this, since we stated before that the
        // remove operation recreates the MulticastDelegate, assigning the
        // delegate to a temporary delegate before doing the null check, and
        // then invoking that temporary delegate should avoid threading problems

        //**************************************************************
        // NOTE THIS IS BEST PRACTICE FOR INVOKING A DELEGATE/EVENT
        // This is thread-safe
        AnotherDelegate aCopy = a;
        if (aCopy != null)
        {
            aCopy();
        }
        //**************************************************************
    }

    // NOTE there is a way to avoid having to worry about null checking, with only
    // a small overhead.  assigning a delegate/event to an initial no-op function will
    // simplify how it is invoked:

    public AnotherDelegate ThirdDelegate = delegate { }; // this assigns a no-op delegate

    // using this method, you'll be able to call the delegate without checking for
    // null or use a temporary variable.  this of course is only true if no code
    // sets ThirdDelegate to null anywhere.

    public void Method()
    {
        // Delegates can be instantiated just like any variable or field
        MyDelegate x = AFunction; // shorthand way of creating a delegate from an actual function
        x = new MyDelegate(AFunction); // the more formal way of creating a delegate

        // if a delegate hasn't been assigned anything, trying to call it will throw an exception
        // not really necessary here though since we just assigned it
        if (x != null)
        {
            int somevalue = x(false, "10");
        }
    }

    public void AnotherMethod()
    {
        // Do Nothing
    }

    public int AFunction(bool somebool, string somestring)
    {
        if (somebool)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        int avalue;
        if (int.TryParse(somestring, out avalue))
        {
            return avalue;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    // EVENTS

    // events are types as delegates but avoid a couple of issues with
    // instantiating delegates as members of a class.  unlike delegates
    // events can only be created within a class or struct (ie not as
    // a standalone type in a namespace).  to create an event, add the
    // event keyword:

    public event AnotherDelegate AnotherEvent;

    // the above is actually the shorthand way of instantiating an event
    // the full way is below:

    private MyDelegate someEvent;
    public event MyDelegate SomeEvent
    {
        add
        {
            someEvent += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            someEvent -= value;
        }
    }

    // EXPLANATION OF HOW AN EVENT DIFFERS FROM A DELEGATE
    // events are actually similar to properties in that they wrap a
    // non-public delegate.  this prohibits an external source from
    // doing two things that most likely aren't desired:
    // external code can't invoke the delegate
    //    external code can't do: classInstance.SomeEvent(...parameters...);
    // external code can't set the delegate
    //    external code can't do: classInstance.SomeEvent = somedelegate;
    // this effectively makes an event something that occurs within class, and
    // controlled by the class, but can be subscribed to by external code.

    // events usually derive from the EventHandler or EventHandler<T> delegates
    // which have the following definitions:
    // void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    // void EventHandler<T>(object sender, T e)
    // the common way to use these is to always send the class instance that
    // raised the event, as well as some event arguments that contain more
    // information about the event.  see below for an example of extending
    // EventArgs.

    public event EventHandler<TakeOffEventArgs> TakeOff;
    public void PerformTakeOff()
    {
        EventHandler<TakeOffEventArgs> takeOffTemp = TakeOff;
        if (takeOffTemp != null)
        {
            takeOffTemp(this, new TakeOffEventArgs("Spaceship", double.MaxValue));
        }
    }
}

public class TakeOffEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public TakeOffEventArgs(string aircraft, double speed)
    {
        Aircraft = aircraft;
        Speed = speed;
    }

    public string Aircraft { get; set; }
    public double Speed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all that sample will look at it and see which answer is best for me.